# Enforce Unique Values - Broken?

Tags: 2010, bug, unique

I've come across a behavior of my SharePoint site that I find just unacceptable.

My Document Repository has a few required columns, one of which, let's call it "ItemNum" has been configured to enforce unique values.

As a user Adds a Document to the repository by browsing for a file, clicking okay, then clicking okay again after adding version comments they are presented with the Add Item form as per usual.

The problem arises if right away they click cancel, or after adding data they click cancel.  That document then get's added...bypassing ALL the required fields, and shows up in the list with blank data, except the file name, of course.

If the user instead adds meta data as expected, and one or more fields fail to pass the validation features chosen in the settings for that column (required, must be unique) the user is then shown the Add Item form with the errors appearing as red text.  Great!  Users need to know what they're doing wrong before continuing.

HOWEVER they can now click cancel and this invalid meta-data appears in the fields of that entry.  Effectively creating an entry that bypasses the validation put in place for good reason.

Using this method anyone could add entries with duplicate or missing field data. This is ridiculous.

Is this a server config issue?  Does this require a hotfix?  Am I just "doing it wrong"? Please, share your insights.

Comment: If you would like to add that as an answer I'll mark it as correct!  Although this may break some look up functionality in some workflows it's not a half bad compromise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally the file is being checked out to the uploaded when not all mandatory information is filled in. The user needs to fill in the required fields before being allowed to publish the document